# GoogleBot Mobile throwing errors on Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-crawlers

Several time during the day, I get error of a page that doesn't have the right format.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template frontpage/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :slim, :haml], :formats=>["*/*;q=0.6"], :locale=>[:en_GB, :en_GB]} in view paths .....
```

The error environment:

```
> HTTP_ACCEPT    
> "*/*;q=0.6" 
> HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING   
> "gzip,deflate"
> HTTP_CONNECTION    
> "Keep-alive" HTTP_FROM     "googlebot(at)googlebot.com"
> HTTP_USER_AGENT    
> "SAMSUNG-SGH-E250/1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0
> Configuration/CLDC-1.1 UP.Browser/6.2.3.3.c.1.101 (GUI) MMP/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Everytime, it appears to be GoogleBot Mobile that is trying to crawl that page.

We are using Rails 3.0.7 with Nginx / Passenger web server. Is there anything to configure related to mobile crawler to avoid this error to be thrown?

Comment: Which way is your locale set for the i18n environment?

Comment: config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :en_GB
    config.i18n.available_locales = [ :en_GB, :nb_NO ]

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue: 
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4176

You can fix it with respond_to and respond_with methods in your controller.